# error in descovering available bluetooth devices in android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to discover available bluetooth devices but it seems `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` is not starting for some reason

I don't understand the following

1. why despite explictly requesting for `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` does `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` statement complain about adding `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission
2. why we need location permission for discovering bluetooth devices
3. while going through the logs I came accross the following

```
3.1 D/BluetoothAdapterService: startDiscovery 
3.2 E/BluetoothUtils: Permission denial: Need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
```

despite I have asked for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions and it doesn't seem to go away
4. what is this error

```
4.1 Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
```

what is wififorward do here ?

I really confused, can someone pls explain this

my `MainActivity.java`

```java
 BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;


BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("Action", action);
    }
};

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
    intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intent);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2);
        }
    }


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 1);
    }

    try {
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        
    }catch (Exception e){
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bf">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BF">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bf"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

here is Logcat

```
2022-07-22 18:48:02.501 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to 
the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:48:02.501 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:48:04.160 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:48:04.160 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to 
initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:48:12.419 1191-5141/? I/PhenotypeProcessReaper: Memory state is: 125
2022-07-22 18:49:02.505 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to 
the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:49:02.505 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:49:04.222 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:49:04.222 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to 
initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:49:11.493 2627-2671/? I/Finsky: [203] goa.run(17): Stats for Executor: 
BlockingExecutor ivq@4a9b5c1[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 
0, completed tasks = 442]
2022-07-22 18:49:11.493 2627-2671/? I/Finsky: [203] goa.run(17): Stats for Executor: 
LightweightExecutor ivq@aefbca7[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 0, queued tasks 
= 0, completed tasks = 700]
2022-07-22 18:49:12.055 2627-2671/? I/Finsky: [203] goa.run(17): Stats for Executor: 
bgExecutor ivq@3b86554[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, 
completed tasks = 4014]
2022-07-22 18:50:02.566 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to 
the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:50:02.566 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:50:04.228 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not   
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:50:04.228 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: 
RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:50:29.450 1191-6722/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched 
acquire!
2022-07-22 18:51:02.567 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 
'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:51:02.567 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:51:04.238 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument 
2022-07-22 18:51:04.239 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: 
RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:52:02.573 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 
'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:52:02.573 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:52:04.293 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:52:04.293 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: 
RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:53:02.627 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 
'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:53:02.628 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:53:04.321 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:53:04.321 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: 
RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-07-22 18:54:02.640 483-483/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 
'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:54:02.640 483-483/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': 
Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:54:04.383 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not 
connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-07-22 18:54:04.383 490-490/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: 
RemoteConnection failed to open pipe}
```

Comment: Do you want to find Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy devices?

Comment: bluetooth classic @MichaelKotzjan